# How to start next queue item in receiver during playback?

Tags: javascript, chromecast

I'm working on a receiver based on Google's reference receiver, to which we're sending a bunch of queued videos. "Normal" playback works fine, the next video is preloaded a few seconds before the current ends, is automatically played and the sender app is updated accordingly.

However, there are some instances in which I need to play the preloaded video before the current one ends, and I haven't gotten it to work. I've managed to play the video using `MediaManager.load`(and `sendLoadComplete()` and `onMetadataLoaded()`), but the sender app gets the wrong data, or no data at all.

Is there a simple way to force a load of the next queued item that I'm missing?